# Share cmake variables between different folders

Tags: cmake

Suppose I have a project setup like so:

```
Project
   '-> CMakeLists.txt
   '-> src
        '-> CMakeLists.txt
   '-> third_party
        '-> CMakeLists.txt
```

In the CMakeLists.txt of third_party I have a variable set like so:

```
cmake_path( APPEND ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} "third_party" OUTPUT_VARIABLE PROJECT_THIRD_PARTY_DIR )
```

In the top level CMakeLists.txt I have both 'third_party' and 'src' included and the third party folder has a particular prebuilt project as well as others that will be built. Is is possible to have access to the variable '${PROJECT_THIRD_PARTY_DIR}' from the src CMakeLists.txt or would I have to move the definition into the master CMakeLists.txt? From what I have found online it seems it can be done by using 'set( .... CACHE INTERNAL )' but I would prefer to use what I thought to be the correct (and newer) features of cmake 3.20 for this path variable.

Comment: Why do you need access to this path in `src`? There may be better ways to access this kind of info, like e.g. getting the `SOURCE_DIR` target property of a target. However this may indicate a flaw in the cmake logic. Furthermore why are *you* editing the *third party* `CMakeLists.txt` file? Btw: Using `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR` instead of `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR` usually is a mistake; In this case the third party cmake file won't work, if used on its own or if your current toplevel cmake file is added to some other project via `add_subdirectory`

Comment: The CMakeLists.txt in third_party is controlled by me and has mostly 'add_subdirectory(...)' that will trigger the builds in the subsequent folders but there is one folder where there is no project, just headers and static libs. I need to include the folders and libraries of that particular third party in order to build src. Re: using CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR, thanks for the tip

Comment: `IMPORTED` and/or `INTERFACE` targets may be an alternative to passing the link/innclude directories around, but whether this is suitable in your case entirely depends on the contents of the directory.

Comment: That is actually really useful. I switched to ```add_library(<project> STATIC IMPORTED GLOBAL)``` in the third_party project folder and used ```set_target_properties``` with the properties ```IMPORTED_LOCATION``` and ```INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES``` and it worked out well and seems like a cleaner solution. I wonder though if there is an option for ```cmake_path``` to share the ```OUTPUT_VARIABLE``` similiar to the ```CACHE INTERNAL``` option of ```set(...)```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should minimize adding variables to your Cmake path.
Paths can change between operating systems and between different installations of the same operating system, so you should save information with Cmake variables.

Even if you are trying to use new Cmake, sticking with the set() command allows for better back-portability with earlier versions of Cmake. I would stay with the `set(<blah name> CACHE INTERNAL )` call and move on.

Another note:

A variable defined in your top level Cmake file is accessible to the lower level CMake files. When the top level Cmake includes another Cmake file, the Cmake files included later also have access to the previous sub-Cmake file variables (with a few exceptions, like the filepath of the previous Cmake file). Ignoring the exceptions, the simple solution to me is to define your 3rd party sources first in your top level Cmake and then the later Cmake files in your own source code can access them.

Comment: According to the cmake documentation [link here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.20/command/cmake_path.html#creating-a-path-variable), it is recommended to use cmake_path over set when creating a path. I'm not sure I understood the 'adding variables to your cmake path' comment though? I'm using 'OUTPUT_VARIABLE' so creating a new path rather than modifying an existing one. As for backwards compatibility, not an issue as we have the minimum cmake version set to 3.20.3 and won't go lower.

Comment: When you call SET() to create a variable in one CMake file, it is visible later in the CMake tree by CMake files included later in the top level CMake file.

Comment: It is indeed but like the documentation says *"While a path can be created with care using an ordinary set() command, it is recommended to use cmake_path(SET) instead"*. This was the reason I asked if ```cmake_path``` had something similiar?

Comment: Looking at the docs for [cmake_path](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/cmake_path.html?highlight=cmake_path), the `cmake_path` doesn't actually represent anything about the physical system. Maybe sources from earlier CMake files can access the same path var, but sub-CMake files still require the order of compilation to be pre-determined or you will run into compilation errors, especially in parallel compiling. I would also not be surprised if there were bugs in this new feature too. I still hold with my original answer: just keep using SET().